# Calculate the number of bars since the first time happened

Tags: pine-script

In *Pine-script*, How can I calculate the number of bars since the **first time** the condition was true in the **current day**?

I used the *bar_index* variable, but I don't know how to set it up for just the current day!

```
HighCrossColor = color.white
int barssincePDH = 0
if high >= PD_High
    HighCrossColor := color.green
    barssincePDH := bar_index
else
    HighCrossColor := color.gray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually count the number of bars and reset the counter when it is a new day.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

newDay = ta.change(time("D")) > 0

var startCounting = false
var condCnt = 0

if (ta.crossunder(ta.rsi(close, 14), 50))
    startCounting := true

condCnt := startCounting ? condCnt + 1 : 0

if newDay
    startCounting := false
    condCnt := 0

plot(condCnt)
bgcolor(newDay ? color.new(color.green, 60) : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this code solved my problem.